# Cant detect orientation on the ios simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I tried :

```
if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown {

print ("UpsideDown")
}
```

I have rotated the simulator UpsideDown ,but It looks like the simulator cant catch that. I dont know if this works in real device ..  I have no device to test that.
Is this a simulator bug ? what can I do to detect the orientation ?

Comment: Disregarding the orientation for a moment, does the *UI* itself orient when upside down? The default setting for an iOS project is not to.

Comment: Why do you need to detect the device orientation? What's your goal? Everything should be based on view size and/or size classes, not orientation.

Comment: @dfd I did check that for my project, I can rotate the simulator but It does not print the message

Comment: @rmaddy, while view size (or bounds) will work, if the app is an iPad app size classes will not. Sometimes a layout works best with different constraints for portrait versus landscape. Regards to the OP - (1) Do you need to know portraitUpsideDown or just portrait? Also, will this UI be part of an app extension? I have code that will detect portrait (but not upside down) because an app extension (at least a photo editing one) cannot use UIDeviceOrientation.

Comment: `UIDevice.currentDevice.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()`

Answer (score 0):

By default when xcode creates your project, it doesn't enable portrait upside down orientation. You can enable the same in `Build Settings` -> `Deployment Info` -> `Device Orientation`. Please see below the screenshot:

[image]